# Unity Static Singleton JSON Serialisation

Tags: c#, json, serialization, unity3d

I have a static `PlayerData` singleton which stores all the data for the player (gold, upgrades, heroes etc) but `JsonUtility` cannot serialise static or private methods so I have implemented a singleton with an intermediate `SaveFile` struct which is used in the serialisation.

`PlayerData` will have more complex objects likes `HeroCollection` etc but for now, I simply have a gold stat.

I am looking for a potentially better alternative solution or simply how to improve this.

Thanks.

```
struct SaveFile
{
    public int Gold;
}

public class PlayerData
{
    static PlayerData Instance = null;

    // # - Private Attributes - #
    int _Gold;

    // ... Heroes
    // ... Upgrades
    // ... Etc
    // # - - - - - - - #



    // # - Public Static Attributes - #
    public static int Gold { get { return Instance._Gold; } set { Instance._Gold = value; } }
    // # - - - - - - - #

    public static void Create(string json)
    {
        if (Instance == null)
            Instance = FromJson(json);
    }

    public static string ToJson()
    {
        return JsonUtility.ToJson(

            new SaveFile()
            {
                Gold = Instance._Gold
            }

        );
    }

    static PlayerData FromJson(string json)
    {
        SaveFile save = JsonUtility.FromJson<SaveFile>(json);

        return new PlayerData()
        {
            _Gold = save.Gold
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are my observations after a quick review:

- First of all your class is not a thread-safe singleton.

  - Please read [Jon Skeet](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/singleton)'s guidance how to implement is properly.
- As I understand you would like to implement a [Memento pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern) in C#.

  - There are a couple of good samples how to implement it properly: [1](https://www.dofactory.com/net/memento-design-pattern), [2](https://exceptionnotfound.net/memento-pattern-in-csharp/), [3](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/memento/csharp/example#:%7E:text=Memento%20is%20a%20behavioral%20design,data%20kept%20inside%20the%20snapshots.)
  - BTW you can also use the [Solid nuget](https://github.com/godrose/Solid) package as well
- Sorry but your naming is terrible, please try to follow some guideline, like:

  - Name your functions / methods in a way that they start with a verb, for example: `SaveState`, `RestoreState`
  - Name Your classes/ structs in a way that they are nouns (w/o adjective), for example: `PlayerState`,`PortablePlayerState`